# Meaning of '/../vendor/autoload.php' in php

Tags: php

I am trying to pull my public folder from xampp to the localhost. I am stuck in an error, and I want to know the meaning of:

**`/../vendor/autoload.php`** soecially what does the "/../" mean ??

Comment: its a root directory to path'

Comment: `..` means one folder up. Its like going back when navigation through folders

Answer (score 2):

`../` means one directory upwards from current location.

So for example, when you want include `/vendor/autoload.php` from within `/app` directory, you have to use

`include '../vendor/autoload.php';`

Comment: @fatemasagar Yes you can, provided the access privileges of the host operating system allow it.